# JMeter 4.0 Not passing post parameter names,

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am using JMeter 4.0 and when I record the log in the post data gets passed as such:

```
POST data:
un=XXXXXX&pw=YYYY&_spring_security_remember_me=on
```

However in my test plan it is being sent like this:

```
POST data:
XXXXXXYYYon
```

Use Equals is checked in the http sampler and I have confirmed that is true in the xml, but JMeter is not passing the attribute name.

Has anyone seen this or have a fix?

Comment: Can you share snapshots from your HTTP sampler and the request tab in view results tree listener

Comment: I apologize I cannot, due to the nature of the project, but as stated in the post, what you see in post data is what was shown in the view results tree, and as I said I have confirmed Use Equals is true in the http sampler.